# How to do Stateless User Authentication of My App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Update from comments:** I want to do Stateless of Restful in HTTP connection. My goal is making a system that when users log into my app, my app's server assigns an id to them. Because if my app cannot do so, other users can access a user pages (if they write something in the URL randomly). And my server's model have users' ids in that time. When users log out my app, these ids are deleted from model. Maybe I can call these system 'Session'.

---

I am performing user authentication in my app. I want to realize Stateless in there that it pass id to users when they log in my app. However, I'm a beginner, so I don't know how to do it. I think I should write these codes in the main controller, but am not sure.  How can I do this process?

**home_controller**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :find_user, only: [:index]

  def index
    @id = params[:id]
    @email = [:email]
    if @id == @user.id  && @email == @user.email
      render :text =>   "sucsess"
    else
      render :text =>   "fail"
    end
  end

  def create
    userData = UserData.new(create_params)
    user = User.find(params[:id]).to_json

    # エラー処理
    unless  userData.save
        @error_message = [memo.errors.full_messages].compact
    end
        end

  private
　　 def find_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id]) # You should specify this code what are your comparing to.
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: "home#index"
  get 'home/index'


  namespace :home, default: {format: :json} do
    resources :index, only: :create
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable      
end
```

Comment: you are using devise gem for authentication ? then why need to check manually?

Comment: yes, my gem have authentication . But I don't know how to pass id to users when they log in app by using authentication of gem.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Would you please correct the question?

Comment: Can you clear this statement more: "it pass id to users when they log in my app"?

Comment: im sorry for my poor explanation.i wanna do Stateless of Restful in HTTP connection.My goal is that  making system that when users log in my app, my app's server give id to them because if my app cannot do so,  other users can access a user pages.(if they write something in URL randomly)And my server's model have users' ids in that time.When users log out my app,these ids are delete from model.Maybe I can call these system 'Session'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user logs in via Devise, they are given a unique token that is stored in the browser's session. When the next page is rendered, the browser will pass it's session cookie to the rails app, and Devise will gather the user token from the session cookie and populate the `current_user` variable with the user object that matches that token.

So if you follow the instructions for setting up [Devise in its README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), then once a user has logged in, you can access that logged in user's User object via `current_user`